# How convert an ISO 8601 date to integer with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iso8601

7.days.iso8601 returns "P7D"

How do the inverse? or Convert "P7D" to an integer?

**updated**

With this pattern P2W2D, ActiveSupport::Duration::ISO8601Parser doesn't work.

I have got this error

ISO 8601 duration: "P2W2D" mixing weeks with other date parts not allowed

B

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23556973/3001761?

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe it's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not working witht this pattern P2W2D

Comment: It wouldn't, that's not valid.

Comment: mmm. the value is from Google API :(